# Interpreting the signal code from atop raw files

Tags: atop

I’ve been looking at `atop` raw file logging using `atop -r -PPRG`.  All looks good except the exit code field is strange.  The last 8 bits are suppose to be the signal number that killed program.

It is mostly that except to get signal you have to subtract 128 from the number,  this is okay,  except signal 9. It is just 9.  You don’t have to subtract 128.

Is there any reason for the difference ?